# Count more than one occurrence in a Django query

Tags: django

I have two models: Players and Tournaments.

Players have also a type of game they play (dota, lol, magic, etc). They can participate in many tournaments at the same time (only once per Tournament). To manage the inscriptions, I use another model called TournamentMatch, that creates a new object for every inscription with the ID of the tournament and the player.

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_dota_player = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_lol_player = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_magic_player = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_start = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField()

class TournamentMatch(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**I want to count the number of Players that have more than two inscription to tournaments and are, for example, dota players.**

I can easily achieve this with a for loop for every player, but for perfomance reasons, I want to achieve this using a Django query.

For example, if I want to count the dota players that have one or more inscription, I will do:

```py
TournamentMatch.objects.filter(
    player__is_dota_player=True
).distinct(
   'player'
).count()
```

I'm sure is possible but I don't know how to count every ocurrence of distinct players on tournaments and only filter those that have more than one (and not only one).

I will appreciate any help or pointers!

Comment: Please show your model definitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
# subquery for counting match per player (note OuterRef which will be linked to the outer query row)
player_match_count_subquery = TournamentMatch.objects.filter(player_id=OuterRef('pk'), ).\
    annotate(match_count=Count('pk'), ).values('match_count', )[:1]

# the main (outer) query which uses subquery output for filtering
Players.objects.filter(is_dota_player=True, ).\
    annotate(match_count=Subquery(player_match_count_subquery), ).\
    filter(match_count__gt=2, )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

this code will produce logically this SQL query:

```
SELECT p.*, tm.match_count
FROM players p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(id) match_count
    FROM tournamentmatch tm
    WHERE tm.player_id = p.id
) tm
WHERE p.is_dota_player = $true
    AND tm.match_count > 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time!
Now I get this exception:
ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.
Could you give me some pointer? I get the idea of the subquery but if there's no easy solution, I will read the documentation more.

Comment: Mmm, now it works but returns an empty QuerySet, which is weird because I have more than 6k records on TournamentMatch. Anyway this was really helpfully and I will research about subqueries to see what can I do. Thanks again!